# How to fetch results from MySQL database using AJAX on button click

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, wordpress

I am new to PHP and ajax so please be easy on me. I am trying to fetch MySQL results using AJAX. I have manged to get to this point from the research I found across the internet. I am doing this inside WordPress if this might help. I am getting this error -

```
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_results() on null in script.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in script.php on line 13
```

test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button">Click</button>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("button").click(function(){

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'script.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    
                    jQuery("p").html(data);

                }
            });
   });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.php

```
 <?php 
 echo' <table border="1">
<th colspan="5" style="text-align:center;"> <h2 class="tomorrow">GRADES</h2> </th>
<tr>
 <th>Day</th>
 <th>Comp</th>
 <th>Exam Type</th>
 <th>Grade</th>
<th>Previous Score</th>
</tr>'?>
  <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM wp_mytab
WHERE date=DATE(NOW())
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM wp_mytabb
WHERE date=DATE(NOW())

ORDER BY date, comp ASC;" );
    foreach ( $result as $print )   {
    ?>
    <tr>
<td><?php echo $print->day;?></td>
<td><?php echo $print->comp;?></td>
<td><?php echo $print->examtype;?></td>
<td><?php echo $print->grade;?></td>
<td><?php echo $print->previouscore;?></td>
    </tr>
        <?php }
  ?>    
</table>

 ?>
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: I'm not a wordpress guy, but what is $spdb. from what it looks, you are going straight to script.php page without any variable inits. That's why $wpdb is null, it's not getting any value anywhere.I guess it should go through some WP init func

Comment: Did you mean these `$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection,'wp_mytab');` ?

Comment: again, I'm not a WP specialist. but basically, yes, you need to init the DB connection (via PDO), and only then you can use the DB connection to fetch things from DB. notice that this is not the best approach in this case. since you are using WP, i't must have some proper sequence to init all the things you need. add wordpress tag to this post to get better answers

Comment: Where is your `script.php` file ? Is this in the ROOT  folder in your Wordpress where all the folder like `wp-content` or wp-admin` are ? Let me know.

Comment: Both `test.php` and `script.php` are in the root folder.

Comment: I added this line to the top of my code which worked. `require_once('wp-config.php');`

Comment: Ideally you have to add `require_once('wp-load.php');` in every custom PHP file in Wordpress for your queries to work..

Comment: And a stylesheet? How do you include that? I added the above code which works but it's lacking styling. I'd wish that it can use the theme/site CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use **`$wpdb`** outside of wordpress code structure in a stand alone PHP file.

To do that you should include some wordpress libraries

Add this at beginning of your php code.

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include_once $path . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php';
```

Make sure your **`$path`** be right